# Script to copy row if column formula value changes to TRUE in google script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have 2 sheets named Active and Expired. in the Active sheet, I have a column that has the formula `=today()+14 > M2`for the entire column, to test the effective dates. once that is `True`, I would like the row to be COPIED over to the Expired sheet.  I currently have

```
function copyTo() {

var sourceSheet = "Active"
var destinationSheet = "Expired"

var check = {
  "col":14,
  "changeVal": true,
  /*"del": false */
  }; 

var pasteRange = {
  "start": 1, 
  "cols": 18
  };

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet()

  if(sheet.getName() == sourceSheet){
    //Get active cell
    var cell = sheet.getActiveCell();
    var cellCol = cell.getColumn();
    var cellRow = cell.getRow(); 

    if(cellCol == check.col){
      if(cell.getValue() == check.changeVal){

        var exportRange = sheet.getRange(cellRow,pasteRange.start,1,pasteRange.cols);

        var pasteDestination = ss.getSheetByName(destinationSheet);
        var pasteEmptyBottomRow = pasteDestination.getLastRow() + 1;

        exportRange.copyTo(pasteDestination.getRange(pasteEmptyBottomRow,1),
                           SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES);

        /*if(check.del){
          sheet.deleteRow(cellRow);*/
        };
      };
    };
  };
```

but my problem lies with `var cell = sheet.getActiveCell();` , as the activecell is never selected so it cannot be evaluated, as `True` is from a formula, which automatically will change based on that date.

essentially, just any row where this formula changes to `True`, i'd like copied over to the expired sheet on an ongoning basis. i cannot use query or filter, as the Active sheet data will be updated on an ongoing basis once the 14 days is up.

Thank you.

Comment: There are no triggers that respond to formula changes.  You can poll the sheet with a timebased trigger.

Comment: can you explain? i've looked into them, doing a 12 hour check with `function createTrigger() {
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('copyTo')
      .timeBased()
      .everyHours(12)
      .create();
}` but again i am still confused how to make the active cell be N2, and iterate over the N column, until FALSE is met and the condition fails, as there may be 4 rows that are meeting the TRUE condition that need to be copied over @Cooper

Comment: If you want to check the value of N2 on 'Sheet1' you can use `SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sheet1').getRange(2,14).getValue()` You don't need to make it the active cell.  The use of activate in macro is due the the fact that the macro is just following you around the spreadsheet doing what you do.  But the use of activate is hardly ever needed in most scripts.

Comment: As Cooper has said, if you need to always look at the same row, or range, you can get that exact range. 
Could you clarify that point? Is your working range fixed? Could you provide a sample sheet to visualize what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: Any reason you want to copy? Why not use the Google Sheets function `filter` or `query` to extract the data from the active tab and dump it in the expired tab?